# How to store the number(length) of similar xpath in a variable in Cypress

Tags: typescript, variables, cypress

I am trying to get the number(length) of similar xpath and store it in a variable

```
    cy.xpath('//tbody[@class="Month"]/tr/td/div[@class="Day"]/div[text()="28"]')
                .its('length').as("CountSimilar")
        cy.log( this.CountSimilar)
        var Nxpath = this.CountSimilar;
```

Any idea how to store the length in a variable

Comment: Where do you plan on using the variable?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you wrap your test in a `function()` to allow use of the alias variable `this.CountSimilar`.

```js
it('tests Nxpath', function() {

  cy.xpath('//tbody[@class="Month"]/tr/td/div[@class="Day"]/div[text()="28"]')
    .its('length')
    .as("CountSimilar")            // adds variable the "this"

  cy.then(() => {

    // Aside from correctly setting "this"
    // you will need to wait for the asynchronous code to complete
    // - here I used a cy.then() to queue the code that uses the result

    cy.log(this.CountSimilar);     // "this" is defined when using function()
    var Nxpath = this.CountSimilar; 

    ...
    // All subsequent code using NxPath must be inside this callback
    // of another callback after another command

    // for example
    expect(NxPath).to.eq(2)  // two day 28 showing

  })
})
```

---

#### Using before blocks to set up variables

Another approach is to use a `before()` or `beforeEach()` block to set up your variable.

All asynchronous code is completed before the test moves on to another block.

```js
before(function() {
  cy.xpath('//tbody[@class="Month"]/tr/td/div[@class="Day"]/div[text()="28"]')
    .its('length')
    .as("CountSimilar")            // adds variable the "this"
})

it('tests Nxpath', function() {

  // now the alias value is usable a plain JS variable 
  var Nxpath = this.CountSimilar;
  ...
})
```

---

#### Page resets

The only exception is when the test page ***resets*** (you will see the test runner clear and restart). Everything set up previously in the browser will be cleared.

For those situations, use the [cypress-data-session](https://github.com/bahmutov/cypress-data-session) package, described in detail here:
[Flexible Cypress Data Setup And Validation](https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/cypresss-data-session/)

Comment: I'm sure this example will not work and `this.CountSimilar` will be undefined the same as in the OP's variant

Comment: Yes you're right - adding a `.then()` will make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Cypress commands are asynchronous, so you have to use a then callback in order to give Cypress time to evaluate the variable.
So you can write your code as follows:

```js
cy.xpath('//tbody[@class="Month"]/tr/td/div[@class="Day"]/div[text()="28"]')
            .its('length').as("CountSimilar")
cy.get("@CountSimilar").then(CountSimilar => {
    cy.log(CountSimilar)
})
```

You can also try using [cypress-theinfy](https://github.com/mbolotov/cypress-thenify) lib to keep your code clean

Comment: How can I pass the value of CountSimilar to another variable?

Comment: do you mean a variable that you use inside the same `it` test? Generally, you can't. Please read the docs: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases#Variables